# Apache Camel Spring Web Services

Tags: java, apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

Since few month i'm learning to build applications in Fuse ESB.

Till today I was thinking, that camel doesn't have any webservices, and if I want to create some webservice which will do for me proxy server I have to use CXF.

CXF is working perfectly and I think, that it's great staff.

Today I found 'spring web service' on page http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html

My question is:

When i'm building a webservice with cxf, there is a webservice, which I can find under :

```
http://localhost:8181/cxf/mywebservice
```

if I would build something with spring web service it will also create for me some url on which I can send some data?

On apache website I found informations, that camel will consume data send to "example.com/GetFoo" address, but I don't exactly know if camel will create for me the GetFoo webservice, if yes should I find it under:

```
http://localhost:8181/GetFoo ?
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

To expose a web service with Spring WS, read the section *Exposing web services*, which basically means you expose the web service the same way you would do with Spring WS.
http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html And then read from there.

Also check out the example that comes with Camel that shows how to exposes a Spring WS: http://camel.apache.org/spring-ws-example.html

Comment: Just to build on top of Claus' answer a bit - Spring WS (and so Camel's support for Spring WS) requires a contract-first web service (eg a WSDL).  If you're looking for something more RESTful, take a look at CXFRS (http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html)

Comment: thanks for answer, @Roy - as a wrote in the begining, now i'm using cxf (CXFRS), and it's working greate, but i was thinking that camel doesn't have any webservices. Thanks again

Comment: Apache CXF can do both WS and RS. The camel-cxf component supports both.